# Why the thebibliography cannot use Chinese?

Tags: bibliographies

I want to add a citation to my paper.

I tried using `thebibliography`, as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,cs4size,UTF8]{ctexart}
\begin{document}
\section{数学软件Wolfram Mathematica\cite{one}}
本文的主要是关于SCARA机器人的运动学和动力学研究，涉及到符号计算、数值计算和图形的可视化，这恰好是Mathematica所擅长的领域，因此首先对Mathematica做一个简单的介绍。

Mathematica是美国Wolfrmn Research公司研制开发的著名数学软件系统，是一种强大的数学计算、处理和分析的工具。自1987年发布系统的1.0版本开始，便迅速广为流传，后经不断改进和完善，现在的最新版本是Wolfram Mathematica 9.0。

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem[one]{(美).Saeed B. Niku 著.机器人学导论：分析、控制及应用[M].电子工业出版社，
2013(TP24/36)}
 \bibitem[two]{袭宗燕 著. Mathematica数学软件系统的应用及其程序设计[M].电子工业出版社，
1996(TP198)}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

However, this doesn't compile.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is

```
\bibitem{<key>} <reference data>
```

or

```
\bibitem[<label>]{<key>} <reference data>
```

With the first way, numbers are assigned, with the second way instead of a number, `[<label>]` will appear when you do `\cite{<key>}`.

Fix your code as

```
\documentclass[a4paper,cs4size,UTF8]{ctexart}
\begin{document}
\section{数学软件Wolfram Mathematica\cite{one}}
本文的主要是关于SCARA机器人的运动学和动力学研究，涉及到符号计算、数值计算和图形的可视化，这恰好是Mathematica所擅长的领域，因此首先对Mathematica做一个简单的介绍。

Mathematica是美国Wolfrmn Research公司研制开发的著名数学软件系统，是一种强大的数学计算、处理和分析的工具。自1987年发布系统的1.0版本开始，便迅速广为流传，后经不断改进和完善，现在的最新版本是Wolfram Mathematica 9.0。

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{one}(美).Saeed B. Niku 著.机器人学导论：分析、控制及应用[M].电子工业出版社，
2013(TP24/36)
\bibitem{two}{袭宗燕 著. Mathematica数学软件系统的应用及其程序设计[M].电子工业出版社，
1996(TP198)}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]